# How to put brushes in a set?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, brush

When I click on the little settings wheel in my brush panel there are various brushes listed on the bottom. 'Basic Brushes', 'Dry Media Brushes' and so on. I'd like to put brushes that I download or create in sets like these to so I can easily find and manage them.

How do I do this?
I tried to search on google but I could only find tutorials on how to create brushes and I want to know how to organise them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a bunch of Brush presets, then choose **Save Brushes** from the **Brush Panel Menu**.

[image: brush presets]

Comment: It's also helpful to clear all the brushes before organized them to save them. Else you'll save the default brushes too, which is unnecessary.